# How to use a JQuery Show/Hide script, to show hidden text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to HTML and know absolutely nothing about JQuery, but I am working on a personal site to learn some HTML. I was trying to have a page where the majority of text would be hidden and the user could click Show / Hide to show what they wanted to see (multiple options).

I found this JQuery code in another post:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#hide1").click(function(){
    $("o1").hide();
  });
  $("#show1").click(function(){
    $("o1").show();
  });
});
```

With the buttons:

```
<button id="hide1">Hide</button>
<button id="show1">Show</button>
```

I understand how to use it, but I want the text it is supposed to show/hide to be hidden when the page loads. I have tried the CSS `visibility:hidden` option but that does not work.

Would anyone be able to suggest something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#showButton").click(function() {
    $("#text").show();
  });
  $("#hideButton").click(function() {
    $("#text").hide();
  });
});
```

```css
#text {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="showButton">Show</button> <button id="hideButton">Hide</button>
<div id="text">Some text</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

not sure if this work but give it a try :D

HTML:

```
<body onload="start()">
```

JS:( change .show() to .hide() if u needed)

```
function start(){
        $("o1").show();
};
```